# I want to reduce the spacing in my asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i want to reduce the spacing inside my web page:

The problem is the buttons below "back" and "next" is not visible without scrolling down

I have posted the code below:

```
 <asp:View runat="server" ID="view_1">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrMgr" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <h1 class="blue" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_viewTitle1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </h1>
                <div style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:none; clear:both;">
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="1" style="border-color: Green; border-width: thin;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" id="tdReadableContent" runat="server">
                                        <div style="height: 167px; width:450px;">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="blue" style="height:16px!important;" colspan="3"><b>Your Current Settings</b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="width:10px"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
                                                <tr id="trUserDetail_read" runat="server">
                                                    <td class="tabRow" valign="baseline">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_userID_Read" runat="server" Text="User ID"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_view1_userID_Read" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                        CssClass="text_box_gray"></asp:TextBox><div class="smallText" nowrap>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<%--(This would be the ID you would normally log on with.)--%></div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="150" class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_panview3_label2_read" runat="server" Text="Store Number "></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_panview3_input2_read" CssClass="text_box_gray" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_surname_read" runat="server" Text="Surname"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_view1_surname_read" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="text_box_gray" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr id="trFirstName_Read" runat="server">
                                                    <td width="150" class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_firstName_Read" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="200">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_view1_firstname_Read" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" CssClass="text_box_gray"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <%--<asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="errorText" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                                                    </td>    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="tabRow">&nbsp;
                                                        <%--<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Employee Number "></asp:Label>--%>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="200">&nbsp;
                                                        <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                                                        CssClass="text_box_3" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>    
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label11"></asp:Label>
                                        <hr class="hrRequestorForm" />
                                        <div id="divRoleDepartment_ReadOnly" runat="server" style="margin-left:20px; height:390px; overflow:auto;" class="tabel1Parent">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="panelStore_Read" runat="server">
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvRoleDepartment_ReadOnly" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                                                            <Columns>
                                                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRole_Read" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
                                                                                            <input type="hidden" id="hdRoleCode_Read" value="<%#Bind('ddl_code') %>" runat="server" />
                                                                                            <input type="hidden" id='hdDepCode_Read' value="<%#Bind('dep_code') %>" runat="server" />
                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ddl_item" HeaderText="Role" ItemStyle-CssClass="roleColumn2" />
                                                                                <asp:BoundField DataField="dep_name" HeaderText="Department" ItemStyle-CssClass="departmentColumn" />
                                                                            </Columns>
                                                                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                                <div class="tabel1Parent">
                                                                                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-color: green; border-width: thin;
                                                                                    width: 390px; border-left: #9787b1 solid 1px; border-top: #9787b1 solid 1px;'>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td class='roleColumn'>
                                                                                            <b>Role</b>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td class='departmentColumn'>
                                                                                            <b>Department</b>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                </table>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        &nbsp;
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" >
                                        <div style="height:160px; width:450px;"> 
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="blue" style="height:16px!important;" colspan="3"><b>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewSettings" runat='server' Text="Your New Settings"></asp:Label> 
                                                    </b></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr id="trUserDetail" runat="server">
                                                    <td class="tabRow" valign="baseline">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_userID" runat="server" Text="User ID "></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="textFieldColumn">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" TabIndex="1" text="Enter User id.." 
                                                            runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                                            CssClass="text_box_highlight"
                                                            onfocus="defaultStyle();"
                                                            onkeypress="ChangeUserIdBackground();"
                                                            MaxLength ="50"></asp:TextBox><span id="starUserId" runat="server" style="color:Red">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserID"  runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserID"
                                                            ErrorMessage=" Required field" ValidationGroup="Form2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><div class="smallText" nowrap>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;(This would be the ID you would normally log on with.)</div></td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left:135px">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserExists" CssClass="errorText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" 
                                                            ControlToValidate="txt_panview3_input2" ErrorMessage="Store should be a number" 
                                                            ValidationExpression="[0-9]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                    </td>    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width="150" class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_panview3_label2" runat="server" Text="Store Number "></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_panview3_input2" runat="server" 
                                                        MaxLength="4" CssClass="text_box_3">0000</asp:TextBox>
                                                        <span id="starStoreNumber" runat="server" style="color:Red">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStoreNumber" runat="server" 
                                                        ControlToValidate="txt_panview3_input2" ErrorMessage=" Required field" 
                                                        ValidationGroup="Form2" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_surname" runat="server" Text="Surname "></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_view1_surname" runat="server" 
                                                            CssClass="text_box_3"
                                                            MaxLength ="50"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <span id="starSurName" runat="server" style="color:Red">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSurName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_view1_surname"
                                                            ErrorMessage=" Required field" ValidationGroup="Form2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr id="trFirstName" runat="server">
                                                    <td width="150" class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_view1_firstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td >
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_view1_firstname" runat="server" 
                                                            CssClass="text_box_3"
                                                            MaxLength ="50"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <span id="starFirstName" runat="server" style="color:Red">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_view1_firstname"
                                                            ErrorMessage=" Required field" ValidationGroup="Form2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="tabRow">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeNumber" runat="server" Text="Employee Number "></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="280">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeNumber" runat="server" 
                                                        CssClass="text_box_3" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        <span id="starEmployeeNumber" runat="server" style="color:Red">&nbsp;*</span>
                                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmplyeeNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmployeeNumber"
                                                            ErrorMessage="Required field" ValidationGroup="Form2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" 
                                                        ControlToValidate="txtEmployeeNumber" ErrorMessage="Enter a numeric value" 
                                                        ValidationExpression="[0-9]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>                                                
                                            </table>
                                            <b><asp:Label ID="lblCaption2" runat="server" Text="Note: All fields are mandatory" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></b>
                                        </div>
                                        <hr class="hrRequestorForm" />
                                        <div style="padding-left:20px;" id="divRoleDepartment" runat="server">
                                            <div class="tabel1Parent">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Panel ID="panelStore" runat="server">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                                            <asp:GridView ID="gvRoleDepartment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                                                                <Columns>
                                                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRole" runat="server" />
                                                                                            <input id="hdRoleCode" runat="server" type="hidden" 
                                                                                                value="<%#Bind('ddl_code') %>" />
                                                                                            <input id="hdDepCode" runat="server" type="hidden" 
                                                                                                value="<%#Bind('dep_code') %>" />
                                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                    <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="roleColumn" ControlStyle-Width="300px" 
                                                                                        DataField="ddl_item" HeaderText="Role" ItemStyle-CssClass="roleColumn" />
                                                                                    <asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="departmentColumn" 
                                                                                        ControlStyle-Width="120px" DataField="dep_name" HeaderText="Department" 
                                                                                        ItemStyle-CssClass="departmentColumn" />
                                                                                </Columns>
                                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                                            <span ID="lbl_chkBx_store_workunit" class="errorText"></span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            &nbsp;
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                </table>
                                                            </asp:Panel>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblException" runat="server" CssClass="errorText"></asp:Label>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <br />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>                                    
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="btn_view1_back" runat="server" Text="Back" CausesValidation="False"
                                                ValidationGroup="Form2" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btn_View1_Next" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Next"
                                                ValidationGroup="Form2" OnClientClick="return check_sel();" UseSubmitBehavior="True" />
                                            <%
                                                'mahesh code
                                                'replaced   OnClientClick="return ValidateDropDown(); with OnClientClick="return check_sel() "  
                                            %>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>  
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </asp:View>
```

Please help @!

Comment: It'd help if you isolate the problem and paste only the relevant parts.

Comment: All are relavant ... there is nothing to isolate there ...

Comment: why do you want to reduce the spacing?

Comment: Why not put your 'Back' and 'Next' buttons at the top of the page, or top and bottom? This looks like a large form, it may not be possible to fit it all on the page without scrolling.

Comment: Its the requirement, it should be on the bottom

Comment: How can *all* be relevant? it is impossible to cut and paste your example and use it, so I'd say: none is relevant. If you want quick help, make it easy on the helpers, create an example that illustrates your situation.

Comment: Well, it's all "relevant" because he has a large amount of stuff to display before the buttons and that stuff is pushing the buttons off the visible screen.  If he trimmed out the large amount of stuff, then the problem would not be visible.

Comment: @Jason, I understand that, but as long as we can't *see* the buggering whitespace, it'll be hard to tell what's up. And if it's just about some scrolling issue: a few lines of code and a resized browser window will do, really. And if it's just about spacing: two `<td>` rows without the bloat would suffice, too, to illustrate the point. In "full-context" cases, a link is better. But all this aside: as long as we can't see, we can't really help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, provided you do not have to support old versions of Internet Explorer, is to use position: fixed to "stick" your buttons to the bottom of the viewable window.

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0px;">
    <asp:Button ID="btn_view1_back" ... /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btn_view1_next" ... />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You say your problem is that the buttons are not into view. You can scroll your control into view by [using this technique](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ViewControl.aspx). Or you can load the page on my screen, I have a bigger monitor.

What I'm trying to say: if it's visible on your screen after redesign, anybody with a smaller screen or a resized browser window still won't see it.

*If you want to-the-point help on your HTML design, I suggest you upload a trimmed down example of your problem that we can copy and paste to test (or show an online link of your current page).*

Answer (score 2):

Lose the tables, or at the very least, remove the unnecessary `<div>` and `<br>` tags.

Comment: +1  Get rid of the tables and do your layout in CSS.  It'll take some time to get used to if you've not done things that way before, but it will give you A LOT more control once you've made the switch.

Comment: I hope you have alot of time and patience to do this layout in CSS and making work cross-browser.

Comment: This pie graph might help illustrate my point :) - http://beradrian.files.wordpress.com/2008/01/breakdown.png